# WebBrowser control doesn't populate on first iteration if loading two controls

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

The issue I am having is I have a WebBrowser control called "Browser." The browser is populated from a different controls created by MEF:

```
 //Apply Button that cretes the HTML that is loaded into the Browser
 btnCreateHTMLPreview(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   //Clears the content of the observable collection
   contents.Clear();

   //usedControls is an observable collection of all loaded controls in the stack panel
   foreach(var control in usedControls)
      control.CreateHTML();
 }

 //Code in the MEF Control that creates the HTML that is will be loaded into the browser
 CreateHTML()
 {
   string tempStuff = null;
   tempStuff += "<h1>" + MyControl.lblHeader.Content + "</h1>\n";
   tempStuff += MyControl.txtTextGoesHere.Text + "\n";

   //Give the HTML back to the Application
   parent.AcceptReport(tempStuff);
 }

 //Application side where it accepts the HTML and loads it into the Browser
 AcceptHTML(string passedInContent)
 {
   //Observable collection that holds the content of all possible MEF Controls
   contents.Add(passedInContent);

   string tempStuffForBrowser = null;
   tempStuffForBrowser = "<html>\n";
   tempStuffForBrowser += "<body>\n";

   //Add the content that was saved earlier
   foreach (var strInd in contents)
      tempStuffForBrowser += strInd;

   tempStuffForBrowser = "<html>\n";
   tempStuffForBrowser += "<body>\n";

   Browser.NavigateToString(tempStuffForBrowser);
 }
```

I did my best above to try and provide the meat of how I am populating the html and add that back into the browser. If there is anything that is unclear please just let me know.

If I have just one control added so that "content" only has the one control in it when I click the button to load the html, it works just fine and loads it in.  However if I have more than one control loaded, I have to click that button twice to get it to show. I found this extremely bizarre. My attempt to solve this was to check and see if there was content in the Browser before leaving the event, but I am unsure how to do this. If anyone has any suggestions or any other ideas on how to solve this problem please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the WebBrowser control has some kind of issue where it doesn't load the first string it gets; I'm assuming there's some initialization that hasn't happened yet. I got it to work by calling

`myBrowser.NavigateToString("");`

from within the constructor of my class, and then using it from then on worked correctly. Hokey but it works.

Comment: Hokey but I will take it...That worked and now everything is falling in place!  Your awesome :-)